# Modal Image Gallery CSS Linking

Tags: html, css, image, modal-dialog, gallery

I am trying to code a modal image gallery on my website. I am currently using a code I found on W3schools.com. They give a simple html code with a css linked to it. I'm not sure why, but they don't give you the css code, it's just linked. Whenever I try to link it on my webpage, it messes with the other css I have linked to that document. How do I stop this from happening? Thanks!

Comment: It will mess up the other css, because some of the classes might be unique. add a unique id or class to the parent element of the modal and prepend this unique id/class before the classes/id of the modal exisitng css.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! The problem is,I don't have access to the css, I just see a link in the html file that looks like this: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">